# pandas dataframe checking columnwise

Tags: pandas, dataframe

In a pandas dataframe df

```
Col1    Col2    Col3

T1      N1      G1

T2      N2      G1

T3      N3      G1

T4      M1      G2

T5      M2      G2

T6      M3      G2
```

I have a suspicion that for G1, N1=N2=N3 and for G2, M1= M2 = M3 and so on, and I want to check it. Can you suggest how I can check it

Comment: Do you wish to check that col2 are all identical values for each value of col3?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could call [`groupby`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html) and `nunique`:

```
>>> df
  Col1  Col2 Col3
0   T1     1   G1
1   T2     1   G1
2   T3     2   G1
3   T4     5   G2
4   T5     5   G2
5   T6     5   G2
>>> df.groupby("Col3")["Col2"].nunique()
Col3
G1      2
G2      1
Name: Col2, dtype: int64
```

This contains the number of unique `Col2` values for each `Col3` value.  If you want to check whether they're all 1 directly:

```
>>> (df.groupby("Col3")["Col2"].nunique() == 1).all()
False
```

Answer (score 0):

A more manual way to do this is:

```
for row in df.iterrows():
     print row[1][1] == row[1][2]
```

This will give you a visual check if the columns match or not.